# Compound sort not working in Spring mongodb

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I have a requirement where the records will be sorted based on created date first and if created dates are same, we will sort on another field called as ratings.

In my Spring mongo project I am doing the following thing:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.with(new Sort(Direction.DESC, "crDate")).with(new Sort(Direction.DESC, "ratings"));
```

For some reasons its only sorting on the first field ie crDate. And if both dates are same, sort by ratings never work.

When i try to check the value of sort object it shows me this:

```
{"crDate":-1,"ratings":-1}
```

Another finding is, mongo takes in the following syntax for compound sorts:
db.abc.find({..some criteria..}).**sort([["crDate",-1],["ratings",-1]])**;

Is this a bug in spring mongodb implementation or I missed something?

Comment: FYIP, Already tried other Sort constructors that takes in multiple Order objects. But no luck

Comment: Could you try running your sort in the mongo shell? Make sure that it sorts by ratings outside of Spring so we can narrow down where the problem is?

Comment: @CraigWilson It works in shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was another constructor that took the List of Order objects. Strange but I tried it with that now and it seems to be working.

I am now using a single with clause and passing in a List of Order

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Spring API Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html?is-external=true%27) it shows you can specify multiple strings to the sort object you are creating in a list. From you snippet above I would suggest you need to only apply the one sort object that takes the two fields, something **like**

```
query.with(new Sort(Direction.DESC, Arrays.asList("crDate", "ratings")));
```

Comment: Already tried that and another Sort constructor that takes in multiple Order objects. But no luck